# How to register lambda call back with const argument?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, callback

I am trying to register a method with  const argument using lambda to a std::function in c++, vs2017

a sample code of what I tried as following

created my interface as below

```
class myInterface
{
public:
    struct Data
    {
        std::string xyz;
    };
    struct myCallback
    {
        std::function<void(const Data*)> m_xStart;
    }
}
```

callback class

```
class MyCallBack 
{
public:
    ~MyCallBack () {};
    void xStart(const myInterface::Data*);
}
```

CPP file

```
void MyCallBack::xStart(const myInterface::Data*)
{
   //do something
}
```

I tried std::bind

```
void run(){
    MyCallBack myObject;
    myInterface::myCallBack instanceMyCallback; 

    instanceMyCallback.m_xStart = std::bind(&MyCallBack::xStart, &myObject, _1); // register
    //lambda
    //instanceMyCallback.m_xStart = [&](const myInterface::Data* Data) { myObject.xStart(Data);  };

}
```

I tried to register with lambda as well but could get it working

```
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type run::<lambda_40402ad3d6aac639e3a7b4960fceb680>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Comment: Works as expected [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/94fG6G93n) (once fixed typos).

Comment: Notice than you store pointer to local variable in your `std::function`, so that `std::function` should only be called in that scope.

Comment: @Jarod42 what typo did you fix? i cant see any change in the code

Comment: Missing `;`, case for `b` in `myCallback`, `std::placeholders` and `#include`.

Comment: @Jarod42 those things I missed actually while putting code to this StackOverflow  ... they are not the issue...

Comment: You have a working version as link. So you might compare with your version to see the diff.

Comment: Please post a [mre].